# Screen capture code runs OK in WinForms but not as a service

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a Windows service to screen capture but it's not working.

The process reaches the `ScrenCapture.Start()` but it does not do anything and does not throw an error.

If I test it in a Windows form the same code works well:

Code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Expression.Encoder.ScreenCapture
Imports isc.isc_utility
Public Class isc_utility_screen_capture
Dim ScrenCapture As ScreenCaptureJob = New ScreenCaptureJob()
Shared SrvDir As String =   System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location())
Function StartRecording(ByVal FileName As String)
    Dim Dir = SrvDir
    Dim FileToRecord As String
    FileToRecord = Dir + "\" + FileName + ".wmv"
    Try
        ScrenCapture.OutputScreenCaptureFileName = FileToRecord
        ScrenCapture.CaptureMouseCursor = True
        ScrenCapture.Start()
        WriteEventLogInformation("Capturing Video.... " + FileName + " " + Date.Now)
        Return FileName
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteEventLogError(ex.Message)
        Return "-1"
    End Try
End Function

Function StopRecording()
    Try
        ScrenCapture.Stop()
        Return 1
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteEventLogError(ex.Message)
        Return -1
      End Try
   End Function
End Class
```

What could be happening?

Comment: have you examined the event log?

Comment: I checked the event viewer and it doees'have any error

Comment: It doesn't look like you've set a capture device. I don't know enough about the Expression encoder to say if this is the problem - Have a look at this page and scroll down to the "Working With Screen Capture" section. The example is in c#, but you should be able to figure it out. If not, go to this site http://converter.telerik.com/ and paste the c# code. You should be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: ok, thanks i will check your recomendations!